# Sending an array of doubles from one python server to another via Flask and requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

I am trying to send an Array of doubles periodically from a python service to another.

As a beginner in `python` I have read a lot about `Flask` and `requests`. And here is a simple example code. I just want to learn the syntax. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with it.

Server1: send an array via flask

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
a=[]
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '{}'.format(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Server 2: get the array and perform some mathematical operations

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://127.0.0.1:5000')
y = r[1] + r[2]
print(y)
```

My main question is: how can I transfer doubles and integers instead of strings via Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use JSON or other data format for data exchange instead of strings.

Example with `json`:

```py
# SEND
from flask import jsonify
...

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    d = {"my_numbers": list(range(10))}  # create data structure
    return jsonify(d)  # respond with JSON reporesentation of data
...

# GET
import requests

r = requests.get('https://127.0.0.1:5000')
if r.status_code == 200:  # request was successful
    numbers_array = r.json()["my_numbers"]  # get [0, 1, 2, ...] from response
    print(numbers_array[1] + numbers_array[2])  # perform math ops
else:  # server is down or wrong request
    print('error getting data from server:', r.status_code, r.text)
```